# Is it possible to use multiple Table Looping Functoids in a BizTalk 2016 Mapping?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper, biztalk-2016

Is it possible to use multiple Table Looping Functoids in a BizTalk 2016 Mapping?

I trying to build a Mapping in BizTalk 2016. In my source schema I have multiple records with multiple elements. What I want to do is map this to multiple instances of a single record in the target schema. Therefore I wanted to use table looping. Below is a example of what I want to do. But it doesn't work the way I want. Thus my question, if it is even possible to do it like that.

[image: Example]

Comment: Should be possible, what's the exact problem you're having?

Comment: Let's suppose I have 4 rows in the Table Looping Grid of T1 and 3 rows in the Table Looping Grid of T2. The records used for the scope of the Table Looping both occur one time. So each Table Looping should be executed one time right? Thus if I test the mapping in the output file there should be 7 occurences of <C></C>. The problem I have is, there are only 4 <C></C> in my ouput and all my values (D, E and F) are arbitrarily distributed over these 4 <C></C>

Comment: Did you figure out if it's just T1 or also T2? You might want to add a Looping Functoid so the mapper understands you want to go over all records.

Comment: Hi Ne0n. Can you please supply a sample input, map and output, and explain how the output differs from what you want?

Comment: This should be possible with regular loopings. Question though: how do A and B relate to each other? Why isn't the parent of B the scope for the table looping?

Comment: "But it doesn't work the way I want."  - what way do you want it to work?